# TFS Build: accessing custom MSBuild file within sequence control flow

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am having hard times attempting to perform the simplest operation: run the custom MSBuild script (placed within dedicated "BuildScripts" folder) from the Lab test running build definition. What it is supposed to do prior to test execution is to trigger the child build, get the built sources and *perform the modification of the config file by the means of MSBuild script*. And that is what I struggle with. Supposing I have specified the build scripts folder among source settings (mapped to $(SourceDir)) and I use the MSBuild activity for running the script, what do I specify in the path for project file location?

Would appreciate any hints you might share.

Thank you.

Comment: What build system are you using? XAML or vNext? And do you mean you don't know what path to specify in the build definition to point to theMSBuild script? Or  what path to specify in the MSBuild script to point to your actual project file?

Comment: Build def is a XAML file. And I mean the path to the MSBuild script itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can select the MSBuild script file in Build Process as soon as you have uploaded the file into Version Control.

Clicking the button below:

[image]

You will get a dialog to select the solution or project you want to build:
[image]

And then click "Add..." button, you will be able to select the file from Version Control.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is what I have ended up with :)

Answer (score 0):

Never heard the "MSBuild script". If you mean to run powershell  script  during the build. So where do you want to specify the path for project file ? In the script or the  configuration of the  build template ? Suggest you to provide a screenshot.

Moreover, you can use "invokeprocess" workflow activity to invoke powershell script during the build.